# Python smtplib ssl sockets take long to create

Tags: python, sockets, smtp, smtplib

I have a very simple program to send mails that uses pythons `smtplib` to send mails via a secure socket. For some reason the socket creation takes around **80 seconds**. This is the code I use:

```py
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(config['SMTP_HOST'], config['SMTP_PORT']) as server:
    # Send mail here
```

After the socket has been created everything runs smooth and fast. A temporary "fix" for the problem is to pass a small timeout, like so:

```
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(config['SMTP_HOST'],config['SMTP_PORT'], timeout=0.5) as server:
    # Send mail here
```

Now the socket creation takes 0.5 seconds.

Anyone knows why this can happen? I use python 3.9. I tested it in python 3.7 but had the same problems. The exact same script runs instantly on other computers, so maybe it's not python related? I run macOS Big Sur 11.0.1.

Comment: Are you saying it takes 80 second to connect, or that after 80 seconds it times out? Your second example suggests that you're not getting connections, you're getting timeouts. If you're getting a timeout then there's almost no information in your question to figure out why.

Comment: The first example takes 80 seconds to run. I don't think I'm getting timeouts because after those 80 seconds it is sending the mail and there's no timeout error. So probably it takes these 80 seconds to connect. Why setting a small timeout helps in this case: no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the problem was, it has been fixed with the latest Mac OS Update.